# Maven loads wrong version of dependency

Tags: maven

In my maven pom.xml I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
    <artifactId>Chart.js</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I build it, maven loads Version `1.1.1` instead of `2.0.2`. I can't explain why this could happen. `mvn dependency:tree` gives me the following output:

```
[INFO] my.group:mypackage:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ...
[INFO] +- org.webjars.bower:Chart.js:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars.bower:angular-chart.js:jar:0.10.2:compile
[INFO] ...
```

So, `Chart.js` is a direct dependency of my project and no other dependency depends on `Chart.js` and forces loading of version `1.1.1`. Even when I look at the effective pom in IntelliJ, there is no dependency for version `1.1.1`, only my dependency for `2.0.2`.

Any idea why maven loads the wrong version?

Comment: It shouldn't be happening, so I would do a couple of sanity checks, e.g., check if you have dependency management section, check if you have a parent and it has dependency management section, try specifying version via fixed range `<version>[2.0.2]</version>`.

Comment: I just add it to a sample project and got `2.0.2` correctly, using maven `3.3.9`. its pom file also looks fine. Are you sure you didn't check on the wrong pom?

Comment: I already checked all that. I never had such a problem before. And I'm working with maven for years now.

Comment: Thanks for your test with the sample project. I'm also on Maven 3.3.9.

Comment: Can you show us all your pom.xml, where does come from  angular-chart-js.jar ?

Comment: Please post a full output of `mvn dependency:tree` and not only excerpts..Also the full pom file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that angular-chart.js:jar:0.10.2 has a dependency to chart.js 1.1.1. You have a conflict here.

Look at this link to see all dependencies:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/angular-chart.js/0.10.2

You need to add exclusion tags when you add the angular-chart.js dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
  <artifactId>angular-chart.js</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.2</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
          <artifactId>Chart.js</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
    <artifactId>Chart.js</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But `mvn dependency:tree` does not show the dependency to me.

Comment: How did you put your command. Did you try what maven recommends : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html .

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. But I find it really strange that `mvn dependency:tree` does not show dependencies of dependencies even if they overrule my own dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately `dependency:tree` shows how dependency is first added, not how its version is finally determined. There are other tools for that, however. For example, in IntelliJ IDEA you can see a dependency graph showing which dependencies were suppressed as duplicates and such.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev how to see which version finally determined?