# maven-surefire-report-plugin not picking up its configuration

Tags: maven, configuration

I've got a problem with the `maven-surefire-report-plugin`. I've added some `reportSet` configurations in the reporting section of my `pom.xml`, and it doesn't seem to pick up this configuration.

I was [lead to understand](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_reporting_Tag_VS_build_Tag) that the reporting section was the way to go for such plugins, but I'm beginning to doubt so.

Here is my `pom.xml`'s reporting section:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>

            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>aggregated-unit-test-report</id>

                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/test-reports/ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>

                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And here is (partly) what I got from running `mvn surefire-report:report-only -X` on that module:

```
// Cropped for brevity
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:3.0.0-M5:report-only' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) aggregate = false
[DEBUG]   (f) alwaysGenerateSurefireReport = true
[DEBUG]   (f) inputEncoding = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG]   (f) linkXRef = true
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\Users\francois.dupire\workspace\forhrm\libs\framework\coverage\target\site
[DEBUG]   (f) outputName = surefire-report
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: be.formatech.forhrm.framework:framework-coverage:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\francois.dupire\workspace\forhrm\libs\framework\coverage\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: be.formatech.forhrm.framework:framework-coverage:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\francois.dupire\workspace\forhrm\libs\framework\coverage\pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) showSuccess = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skipSurefireReport = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xrefLocation = C:\Users\francois.dupire\workspace\forhrm\libs\framework\coverage\target\site\xref-test
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[WARNING] Unable to locate Test Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
// Cropped for brevity
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.976 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-04T17:24:57+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

We can clearly see that everything's wrong, from start to end:

- the version is 3.0.0-M5 while I specified 2.22.2;
- the linkXRef parameter is true instead of false;
- the output directory hasn't change either.

Am I missing something on how this plugin's supposed to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. the version is 3.0.0-M5 while I specified 2.22.2

Whole problem is that you run the command `mvn surefire-report:report-only` and you expect `reporting` section to be activated. You did nothing but executed the plugin and therefore the section in `build/plugins/plugin` is activated including the version `2.22.2` and not the `reporting` section. If you want to activate the `reporting` section, you have to run the command `mvn site` and then whole project Page would be generated.

**If I was in your position and wanted to generate only Surefire report, then I would use the same configuration in `build/plugins/plugin/maven-surefire-report-plugin` as you did it in the `reporting` section now.**

```
    <configuration>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <outputName>test-reports/ut</outputName>
    </configuration>
```

2. the linkXRef parameter is *true* instead of *false*

The same answer as in 1.

3. the output directory hasn't change either

Proper Maven behavior relies on proper reading of documentation, see the [link](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html).
Please use the parameter `outputName` instead of `outputDirectory` in your case (when `linkXRef` is set to *false* or override the default Maven property `project.reporting.outputDirectory`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback :-). I'll try that tomorrow at work. I didn't understand the surefire-report phase was bound to the plugin configuration, it's good to know.

As for the directories, are you sure reportsDirectories does what you say? In the documentation I read that it points to the XML files surefire-report-plugin should use to generate its report, not to the output directory (which should be defined in outputDirectory, but isn't surely because I'm using the reporting section ;-))

Comment: I have modified the configuration so that I have removed `outputDirectory` and use nested directories in the `outputName`. Pls use this. I am the Apache developer and the developer of Surefire project. If you have any feature or a bug fix requirements, we can discuss in on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but I believe there's either a bug here OR the documentation is incorrect. Referencing: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#configuring-reporting-plugins

At time of writing, it reads:

- mvn site

> It uses only the parameters defined in the  element of each reporting Plugin specified in the  element, i.e. site always ignores the parameters defined in the  element of each plugin specified in .

- mvn aplugin:areportgoal

> It uses firstly the parameters defined in the  element of each reporting Plugin specified in the  element; if a parameter is not found, it will look up to a parameter defined in the  element of each plugin specified in .

Given this configuration

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.anemortalkid</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sample-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.anemortalkid</groupId>
                <artifactId>sample-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <word>fromBuild</word>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.anemortalkid</groupId>
                <artifactId>sample-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <word>fromReporting</word>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

And the report mojo

```
@Mojo(name = "word", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.SITE, threadSafe = true)
public class SampleReport extends AbstractMavenReport {

  @Parameter private String word;

  protected void executeReport(Locale locale) throws MavenReportException {
    getLog().info("Word is " + word);
  }

  public String getOutputName() {
    return "word.html";
  }

  public String getName(Locale locale) {
    return "word";
  }

  public String getDescription(Locale locale) {
    return "Prints a word from config";
  }
}
```

The behavior I expect when doing `mvn site` and `mvn sample-report:word` to BOTH print:

```
[INFO] Generating "word" report          --- sample-report-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:word
[INFO] Word is fromReporting
```

Since:

> It uses firstly the parameters defined in the  element of each reporting Plugin specified in the  element; if a parameter is not found, it will look up to a parameter defined in the  element of each plugin specified in .

I defined word in reporting, so it should always get the configuration from there.

However the result of invoking the goal directly, contradicts the documentation:

```
$ mvn sample-report:word
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< io.anemortalkid:config-print >--------------------
[INFO] Building config-print 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sample-report-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:word (default-cli) @ config-print ---
[INFO] Word is fromBuild
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Reproducible sample: https://github.com/AnEmortalKid/sample-report-plugin

Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7006 to confirm

Answer (score 0):

First, use `mvn dependency:tree` to see if any other plugin has a `3.0.0-M5` dependency to `maven-surefire-report-plugin`.
If you find one, you might have to [setup an exclusion (as in here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139885/6309) in order to force your declaration to hold.
IntelliJ IDEA could also help showing you can which dependencies were suppressed as duplicates.

Check also if there is a profile (possible active by default) which would explain why your configuration is ignored.
I don' t see [any obvious bug report on a wrong `outputDirectory`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-259?jql=project%20%3D%20SUREFIRE%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22maven-surefire-report-plugin%20wrong%20outputDirectory%22), so [its usage](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html) must be off. For instance, as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/efenglu/06dd5e05d6946c768059e36e7b5f3bab), check your `<build>` section.